# how can I change line to paragraph in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to change multiple line to paragraph with `<p>` warp in HTML.
Is there any shortcut key or package could help me with this?

Comment: Please do some own research before asking on SO. https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection

Comment: @VincentOrback I did research, just can't find it by my keywords. What's your keywords for this question? The answer below is work around, it is nothing about HTML (My question is actually HTML focused).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more like a superuser question, but with the multiline editing it can be easily done in Sublime: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXuBgSpLpK4

Just select all the paragraphs, press cmd+shift+l, to place a cursor at the end of every line, then you can put `</p>` there.

The next step is to jump to the beginning of the lines by pressing cmd+'<-' (left arrow key) and put `<p>` there.

Comment: I thought it should be some package to help me... well, it is cool inside already :)